# How to start passenger in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am having two application in my single apache server.
Say App1 and App2.

Now I want to start passenger on only one application.

How can I start and stop passenger on single application?

Comment: Please formulate your question.Apache is not capable to run Rails application, we need passenger module configure with apache to run rails application.

Comment: Yes, I want to start passenger in only application to start rails application. Is it possible to start passenger in only one rails application and keep other application off?

Comment: Just remove the entries of virtual hosts from apache configuration OR run application separatly e.g . if /var/www/app1 is rails application then - go to app1 and passenger start -p 3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add passenger as a module into Apache, there's a script which comes with passenger gem, if you have passenger in your PATH, you just enter in terminal:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Comment: Is this starts passenger automatically when i start apache server?

Comment: not really, but it is a tutorial and at the end it tells you which lines you should add to apache configuration

Comment: Ok. I am using apache as a web server and passenger as a application server. When I start only apache rails application is started. So is apache starting passenger instance automatically?

Comment: Passenger is not a webserver (passenger standalone uses Nginx as a webserver). Passenger is a module, which can be used in Nginx or Apache for running Rails application

Comment: If I start only apache. Is it start rails application using passenger?

Comment: if you followed the instruction given by the installer, then yes

Comment: In which directory apache configuration file is present?

Comment: on debian linux it's usually `/etc/apache2/` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` for virtual servers

Answer (score 0):

try this way to start passenger

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#_usage